# Merge and aggregate list entries with pandas, without removing fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have lists of this format:

```
['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 1233],
['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533],
['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 2345],
['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345]
```

I would like to aggregate the numbers at the end if the first three strings are identical and remove the duplicate entry. Such that:

```
['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 3578],
['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533],
['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345]
```

I know how to `.groupby([0])` with pandas but that usually erase all the columns that are not grouped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
#add data to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D'], 
                  data = [['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 1233],
                        ['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533],
                        ['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 2345],
                        ['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345]])
#group the dataframe and sum the last column    
df.groupby(by=['A','B','C']).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [137]: pd.DataFrame(d).groupby([0,1,2]).sum().reset_index().values.tolist()
Out[137]:
[['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345],
 ['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 3578],
 ['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533]]
```

where `d` is a list:

```
In [138]: d
Out[138]:
[['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 1233],
 ['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533],
 ['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 2345],
 ['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you get your list into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 1233],
        ['cat', 'black', 'mammal', 1533],
        ['bear', 'brown', 'mammal', 2345],
        ['bear', 'black', 'mammal', 2345]
    ])
```

Use `groupby` + `sum`

```
df.groupby([0, 1, 2])[3].sum().reset_index()


      0      1       2     3
0  bear  black  mammal  2345
1  bear  brown  mammal  3578
2   cat  black  mammal  1533
```

To get your list back... See @MaxU's answer.